# Get a Stream from an XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net

As a result of a stored procedure I get a `SqlXml` object, from which I can call `CreateReader` to get a standard `XmlReader` so as I can handle it in my dll.

In the business layer of the application, I have an `XMySerializer` that could read the xml and instantiate the business object.

However the `XMySerializer.Deserialize` function takes a System.IO.Stream as an input.

So, the question is how could I get a `System.IO.Stream` **from** a `System.Xml.XmlReader` ?

Counterwise would be easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no way, getting the stream, the XmlReader uses. The Workaround would be to use `XmlReader.ReadOuterXml()` to get the whole XML as a string and put it in a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Note that this has the overhead of decoding the [usually UTF8] encoded XML (with mostly single bytes per character), to a string where each character is two bytes (some chars are more I think). So there's the text decoding cost and the double sized memory footprint to consider.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you can. It just requires some libraries that not everyone uses, because they're part of BizTalk. If you have access to the BizTalk runtime, you can utilize an [XmlTranslatorStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb750427.aspx) to provide a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) instance from an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) instance:

```
var xmlStream = new XmlTranslatorStream(xmlReader);
```

[There are 3 constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.streaming.xmltranslatorstream.xmltranslatorstream.aspx) you can use.

Yeah, extremely hefty requirements to get a Stream from an XmlReader, so you can see why most answers equate to "you can't get there from here!"

Answer (score 7):

The `XmlReader` may or may not be backed by a `Stream`. I've fooled around with some methods using reflection to try to get the `Stream` or `TextWriter` backing the XmlReader, but in the end I think it's probably most straightforward to write the object to a new stream; I'd recommend this method over the accepted answer because the accepted answer won't perform very well on large documents, and this is basically a simplified version of what the BizTalk version in Jay's answer will do (BizTalk does some automatic detection of whether it should use a `FileStream` or `MemoryStream` and has some other special handling for the XML):

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static MemoryStream ToStream(this XmlReader reader)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        reader.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms;
    }

    public static FileStream ToStream(this XmlReader reader, string fileName)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        reader.CopyTo(fs);
        return fs;
    }

    public static void CopyTo(this XmlReader reader, Stream s)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.CheckCharacters = false; // don't get hung up on technically invalid XML characters
        settings.CloseOutput = false; // leave the stream open
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(s, settings))
        {
            writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
        }
    }
}
```

`CopyTo` would allow you to set your stream up however you like; `ToStream` gives you a couple helpful common cases where you just want to quickly get a regular `MemoryStream` (for smaller XML files) or use a `FileStream` (for larger ones).

Of course, in the end, if you're really doing this for serialization purposes, it'd be good to just add an overload to your serialization class like:

```
XMySerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader reader, object graph)
```

Both `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` in the BCL follow that idea...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. `XmlReader` is an abstract class that has many implementations (including some that read from streams but others have nothing to do with streams). However you can write the data in this XML reader to a `System.IO.MemoryStream` and then provide this stream to your `XMySerializer.Deserialize` function.